# How to query in a text for a sequence of words but not necessarily one immediately after the other in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-11

Is there any way to perform a full text search for a sequence of words? The order is important but the distance between words is not. The words could be next to each other or at `n`-words apart.

For example, given the following text: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`.

The following searches should return `true`: `quick brown`, `quick jumps`, `jumps dog`.

But the following should return `false`: `brown quick`, `jumps fox`, `jumps brown`.

The `<->` operator will return `true` only if the two words are exactly one after the other. The `<n>` (where n > 0) will return true only if the second word is exactly at the distance `n` from the first word.

The solution that comes to my mind is to use the `&` operator and then to filter additionally using `LIKE '%firstword%secondword%'` but this is slow if there are many documents (and there will be 100.000+ documents in the table).

Is there any fast way in Postgres to do this?

Comment: "but this is slow"  Then make it faster.  You haven't given us the information to help you do that.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info.

Comment: 100,000 is not that many.  How many of the documents will contain 'jumps & fox', but then fail due to ordering?

Comment: @jjanes I'm not sure, it depends on the searched terms. I was wandering why does not Postgres have such an operator, especially that it does use the distance between terms in the `ts_rank_cd` function.

Comment: "I want these words in this order, even if one is in chapter 3 and one is in chapter 27" doesn't seem like a very meaningful operator to me.  If we started adding things like there, where would we stop?  And if we had it for GIN, it would still pull all documents with both words, the later recheck for word order, so would have much the same performance as doing the "recheck" yourself, although a nicer syntax.  Perhaps you could add such an operator to RUM (https://github.com/postgrespro/rum), however, as it stores order info in the index.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions here:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'::text AS input
)

SELECT input
FROM yourTable
WHERE input ~* '.*\yquick\y.*\yjumps\y.*';
```

### Demo

The regex being used here, to detect `quick` and `jumps` as separate words in the input, in that exact order, is:

```
.*\bquick\b.*\bjumps\b.*
```

Comment: Isn't this slow? There could be potentially thousand of records to check.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Yes, regex is not necessarily the fastest approach.  If you need top performance then look into using full text search.

Comment: It can be accelerated with a pg_trgm index. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html.